# Compiler Error Message: CS1061 ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to code a `DropDownList` that will have an `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event but I can't make it work.

So here's the code on my `.aspx`:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DDLSample" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLSample_SelectedIndexChanged" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Sample1" Value="0"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Sample2" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Others..." Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And a `TextBox`:

```
<asp:TextBox  ID="txtOthers" runat="server" Visible ="false" CssClass="form-control" ></asp:TextBox>
```

What I plan to do is that when `Others...` is selected from the `DropDownList`, it will show the `Others` field.

on my `aspx.cs`, I have this code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     DDLSample.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(DDLSample_SelectedIndexChanged);
     DDLSample.AutoPostBack = true;
}

void DDLSample_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (DDLFindings.SelectedValue.ToString() == "2")
         txtOthers.Visible = true;
     else
         txtOthers.Visible = false;
}
```

But still, I keep getting this error:

> CS1061: 'sample_aspx' does not contain a definition for
>   'DDLSample_SelectedIndexChanged' and no extension method
>   'DDLSample_SelectedIndexChanged' accepting a first argument of type
>   'sample_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DDLSample_SelectedIndexChanged` is private and your `aspx` cannot access the private methods. You can either remove `OnSelectedIndexChanged="DDLSample_SelectedIndexChanged"` from your `DropDownList` because you already have:

```
DDLSample.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(DDLSample_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Or make `DDLSample_SelectedIndexChanged` protected:

```
protected void DDLSample_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks! protected works! can you explain why? I'm kinda new to this and I really don't know the reasons behind these codes. Thank you!

Comment: @Katherine...Because without define `protected` your  `DDLSample_SelectedIndexChanged` method is private and your `aspx` cannot access the private method.